# Implementing Monitor with signaling using mutex and condition variable in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

Did any body implemented a Monitor with signaling (wake up waiting threads) using a mutex and condition variables in C++.

I dont know how to start. Any sample code or online article will be great.
Are there any open source libraries who have implemented these?

I need for windows and linux. But to start with windows(win32) will be fine.

Comment: Sorry but what is your question, writing some portable code for mutexes and conditions or learning how to use them ?

Comment: I wanted the monitor class with signaling in c++ which uses mutexes and condition variables. Writing a monitor class on my own would have been difficult and time consuming too. I was sure that someone would have implemented it , but was unable to find it. So I posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Qt Quarterly article](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq21-monitors.html) explains how to do this using Qt's QMutex and QWaitCondition. But you should be able to reimplement it with whatever mutex class you want to use..

See also the more advanced example in [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq22-monitors2.html)..

Comment: +1 very clear article, and very easy to apply to other toolkits

Answer (score 2):

Check out [boost::thread::condition_variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) together with samples.
It can be used to wait for the condition with or without a timeout. I think it's a fairly elegant solution which should do exactly what you need in this case, and do it in a portable way.

Answer (score 0):

All threading programming I've done in C++ used pthreads, which has the fundamental building blocks you need. This [article](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0VVT/is_10_2/ai_n24998136/) discusses using those building blocks for Monitors

For some reason the link doesn't work, paste the same URL into a browser and it does.

```
http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0VVT/is_10_2/ai_n24998136/
```

Answer (score 0):

I made one here for posix systems: http://asgaard.homelinux.org/svn/cpp/threadqueue/ There's a C variant here: http://asgaard.homelinux.org/wordpress/?p=9

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla's platform abstraction library [NSPR](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr) 
(the Netscape Portable Runtime) has a monitor abstraction which is cross-platform.  It's a "real" implementation (actually used in Firefox for example) so it's not simple.  But it is a monitor.

Source: [prmon.c](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/nsprpub/pr/src/threads/prmon.c), [prmon.h](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/nsprpub/pr/include/prmon.h)

Documentation: [prmon.html](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/prmon.html)